# RSelenium Chromedriver Timing Out

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver, rselenium

I built a webscraper using RSelenium and Chrome. It used to work. Suddenly, it won't even open the browser!

I ran:

```
rD <- rsDriver(port=sample(4000:5999,1),
                       browser="chrome",
                       chromever = "88.0.4324.96",
                       extraCapabilities = eCaps)
```

And I receive the message:

```
Selenium message:Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'Lees-Air.attlocal.net', ip: '2600:1700:4a53:2010:0:0:0:2f%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.15.5', java.version: '15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
     Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.
```

Has anyone else seen this issue --where Chrome 88 keeps timing out trying to reach the driver on a Mac? Do you have a solution? I saw some people saying they experienced this and that switching to Firefox solved it. Firefox does, at minimum, open the browser for me. However, Firefox is too slow. I can run tests manually only --anytime I try to automate them, Firefox slows down to an absurd degree and on the FIRST line of code. If I run literally the exact same single command manually, it works just fine. Any recommendations to either get chrome to run again or speed up firefox?

Comment: Update chrome and try different versions.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a typo in the configuration part and you need to replace `chromever` with **`chromedriver`**.

Comment: 'Chromever' refers to 'chrome version'. Chromedriver is not an argument for rsDriver.